# In angularJs Assign a scope variable containing JSON Array of Objects to an Object property inside another JSON Array

Tags: arrays, angularjs, json

My need is to create multiple rows with 2 fields one dropdown and one textbox.
I created a Json array for holding the each row as an object.I want to add the dropdown as an json array of object to my json array of object containing the rows.
My code is below:

```js
   //Declare empty array to add new rows
        $scope.searchList ={
            sources: [{
                id: $scope.rowId,
                srcCd: '',
                srcId:''
              //want to add sourceCdMap property  and assign the json array which is in another scope variable $scope.sourceCodeMap
              
              }]
        }
```

```html
     <table>
                <tr ng-repeat="source in searchList.sources track by source.id">
                    <td>
                        <div >
                            <label >Source Name</label>
                            <div >
                                <select class="form-control selectWidth" autofocus ng-model="source.srcCd"
                                        ng-change="changeSourceNew(source.id,source.srcCd)"
                                        ng-options="source.value for source in source.sourceCdMap"></select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div >
                            <label >Source ID </label>
                            <div><textarea id="source.textarea" autofocus ng-model="source.srcId"  rows="4" cols="50"   placeholder="enter SrcIds"></textarea>
                            </div>
                          
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    
                </tr>
            </table>
```

I want to add a "sourceCdMap" property to the json array of object $scope.searchList  which will contain the dropdown values from another json array of object stored inside $scope.sourceCodeMap.

I tried like below but the dropdown is null :

```js
        
         initializeSourceCodeMap();

             var initializeSourceCodeMap = function () {
            $searchUtilityRemoteService.getSourceCode().then(function (resultMap) {
                $scope.sourceCodeMap = resultMap;
                $scope.sourceCodeMap.sort(sortSrcCodeBy("value"));
                $scope.selected = $scope.sourceCodeMap[0];
                $scope.searchIdForm.srcCd = $scope.selected.code;
            }, function (reason) {
                $scope.sourceCodeMap = null;
                //log error
            })
        };

    //Declare empty array to add new rows
        $scope.searchList ={
            sources: [{
                id: $scope.rowId,
                srcCd: '',
                srcId: '',
                sourceCdMap: $scope.sourceCodeMap
            }]
        }
```

FYI the "$scope.sourceCodeMap" is working in other parts of the code or when I try to log it in my console.

Any help is appreciated  on how to assign this scope variable "$scope.sourceCodeMap" (which is actually a json array of objects in itself) to the new property "sourceCdMap" in the Json Array "$scope.searchList"

Answer (score 0):

Try logging inside this function

```
function (reason) {
            $scope.sourceCodeMap = null;
            //log error
        }
```

to see if maybe your **$scope.sourceCodeMap** is always null because of it.

If that's not the case, try using **$scope.apply();**, so that the html can see your changes. Beware of asyncronously calling it.

Comment: initializeSourceCodeMap() is always working as scope.sourceCodeMap is also logging the values the only problem is assign it correctly ...now I ma trying with angular.copy($scope.sourceCodeMap) assign to the json array property